# Create simple asynchronous server

Tags: python, asynchronous, twisted

I start to learn Twisted and try to complete my first task. I have next server code:

```
class TextProtocol(Protocol):

    def connectionMade(self):
        text = self.factory.text
        self.transport.write(text)
        self.transport.loseConnection()

class TextServerFactory(ServerFactory):

    protocol = TextProtocol

    def __init__(self, text):
        self.text = text

from twisted.internet import reactor
reactor.listenTCP(4444, TextServerFactory("Twisted"))
reactor.run()
```

This code send text to client immediatelly. But actually I want to send data, by letters: if  we will have a lot of clients, server should send letter by letter successively. I think SERVER log should be something like this:

```
Client #1 connected

Sending "T" to client #1
Sending "w" to client #1

Client #2 connected

Sending "T" to client #2
Sending "i" to client #1
Sending "w" to client #2
Sending "s" to client #1
Sending "i" to client #2
```

.....

If i will create loop in protocol it will be blocking operation.
Could you help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TCP is going to group/batch/split things as it see fit (its trying to optimize the connection), see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7853650/3334178) by Glyph or this more detailed [How can I force a socket to send the data in its buffer](http://www.unixguide.net/network/socketfaq/2.11.shtml) article

If you *really* want to do this, and mind you your trying to force TCP to do something it doesn't want, then Jean-Paul's answer is pointing that the fact that you *might* be able to get a char-by-char flush on TCP if you write one char at a time with a few second wait in-between each char.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at `twisted.internet.task.LoopingCall` and `twisted.internet.IReactorTime.callLater`.